# UTF-8 in output format - jetBrains

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

Weird, I am using Webstorm 5.0.1 to test some javascript with jstestdriver. it really rocks but I can't get the my console.log(alert) to output in UTF-8 format!

I've tried many things and left pondering if this is even possible in this IDE.

So when i assert that text A is equal to text B the assert returns true but the console outputs this:

**Text A (hard coded expected result)**

```
Snart har du ditt Silverkort! Tjäna 735 poäng och bli Silvermedlem.
```

**Text B (console output)**

```
[LOG] Snart har du ditt Silverkort! Tj�?¤na 735 po�?¤ng och bli Silvermedlem.
```

Comment: Looks like a [known bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13840).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is [already fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-13840), try the next EAP or release build when it becomes available.

> The problem isn't in JsTestDriver IntelliJ plugin's code, but in
>   JsTestDriver-1.3.5.jar core library that is bundled by the plugin.
>
> "[Issue 85](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/issues/detail?id=85): Allow a different character set to be set when running tests"
>
> Next JsTestDriver IntelliJ plugin version will bundle patched version
>   of JsTestDriver-1.3.5 ([patch details](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Patched+JsTestDriver-1.3.5)).